# Cannot create external database table with the DATA DIRECTORY clause

Tags: permissions, mariadb, external-tables

I would like to create a database table in an external file outside of the standard data directory.

The following works:

`create table eh_extern (c1 integer)  engine=innodb data directory = '/tmp';`

I created a test subdirectory of my home directory and set its permissions to 777 and its owner to mysql:mysql

Directory permissions are:

`drwxrwxrwx 2 mysql mysql 4096 Nov 17 09:55 test`

The following does not work:

`create table eh_extern (c1 integer)  engine=innodb data directory = '/home/tx-team/test';` 
The error is:

`Can't create table` eh`.`eh_extern`(errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")`

The error in the syslog reads:

`Nov 17 09:56:39 txteam-PD14RI mariadbd[1149]: 2023-11-17  9:56:39 75 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.

Nov 17 09:56:39 txteam-PD14RI mariadbd[1149]: 2023-11-17  9:56:39 75 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mariadbd does not have the access rights to the directory.
`

What can I do to prevent the error?

OS is: Linux 5.15.0-88-generic (Ubuntu), Server is: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Systemd started services don't have access to /home directories.

systemctl edit mariadb.service and add

```
[Service]
ProtectHome=false
```

ref: [KB systemd](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/systemd/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The error remains exactly the same, though, after the proposed edit and restarting the service.

Comment: Now I got it. When editing the conf file I had just changed the ProtectHome directive instead of adding it to the top of the file. Now, with the directive at the proper place, it gets copied into override.conf and works as intended. Thank you very much.

Comment: Changing files by hand can be done, just needs a `systemctl daemon-reload` to be re-read. But `systemctl edit` is a good way to ensure that a minimal set of change exist and the service can be updated with the next package with everyones intentions take care of.